# Fastest way to share data objects between a Java server and a C# client

Tags: c#, java, serialization

What is the fastest way to share data structures between Java and C#?  I want something where I can literally send a "car" object or a "foo" object and have it serialized and deserialized on both server and client.

Comment: Fast as in performance or fast as in "I want to get this working ASAP?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL (SOAP) is *fairly* interchangeable. If you want something less chatty, anything like Google's "protocol buffers", "ICE" (ZeroC), etc offer interchangeable binary serialization and code generation.

For .NET / C#, there are currently two viable protocol buffers implementations [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/OtherLanguages); protosharp is essentially inactive and incomplete) - either would be fine, but neither currently has a complete RPC stack, so you'd have to handle message passing yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use IKVM, it's a Java-like environment on top of .NET; you could use Java serialization on IKVM and use interop to use the objects from "regular" .NET languages.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/) seems like a good idea. But if that doesn't meet your needs especially since it is still in development.  However, Uri's post points you in a good direction with the use of xml and passing messages, which can be built back together on either side.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to use a SOAP web service on the server and have the client consume the web service?
The object's data structure would be described in the WSDL for the web service.